# async task resulting in long load times

Tags: c#, async-await

See the following code that calls an external api and returns the results. This is then used in a razor view:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetEventsForCalendar(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> execute = async ()
         =>
        {
            using (var client = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AdministrateHttpClient>())
            {
                var requestUrl = _config.BaseCrmUrl +
                                 string.Format(
                                     "events/events?_page={0}&course.categories.id__in={1}&_display=id,title,prices,default_price_id,code,sold_out,delegates_max,places_reserved,tax_type,start,status,end,sessions,delegates_booked,location_object,location&_order=start&is_cancelled=false&start__gt={2}&type__ni=session&is_iht=false",
                                     page, category, DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd:THH:mm:ssZ"));
                var result = await
                    client.GetLoggedAsync(requestUrl);
                return result;
            }
        };

        return await ExecFunc(execute);
    }
```

This is currently taking approx. 30-60 seconds to load when I call this from the the controller.

Are there any methods for speeding this up?
Please let me know if you need further code to understand what this function does.

EDIT - Added ExecFunc

```
public TResult ExecFunc<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Exception(exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Edit 2 - Added GetLoggedAsync

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetLoggedAsync(string requestUri, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _logger.Info(GetOutgoingLogText(requestUri, "GET", string.Empty, requestId, caller));
        var result = await GetAsync(requestUri);
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _logger.Info(GetReturnLogText(result, "GET", content, requestId, caller));
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT 3 - Chain of calls:
Initial call (in controller) - finallist is just a text string:

```
try
        {
            model.Events = await _eventService.GetEventsForCalendar(finallist);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.Events = new StaticPagedList<Event>(Enumerable.Empty<Event>(), 1, 1, 0);
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }
```

Task:

```
Task<IPagedList<Event>> GetEventsForCalendar(string category, int page = 1);
```

Task:

```
public async Task<IPagedList<Event>> GetEventsForCalendar(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        var response = await _eventRepository.GetEventsForCalendar(category, page);

        var result = await response.ReadPagedJsonData<Event>();

        return result;
    }
```

Task:

```
 Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetEventsForCalendar(string category, int page = 1);
```

This leads to the initial script above

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172919/discussion-on-question-by-paul-almond-async-task-resulting-in-long-load-times).